# Xamarin Zxing Mobile Camera permission

Tags: xamarin, google-play, mvvmcross, zxing.net, zxing.net.mobile

Whenever trying to upload my application to play Console i am getting a message that i need to specify privacy policy because of my app requesting Camera permission.

While Zxing net requeries the permission, my app does not use any of the library functionality requering camera.

Is there a way to remove the camera permission from the final androidmanifest?

What i've tried is adding tool:node="remove" which no result at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using any of the camera parts of ZXing.Net.Mobile, then you can probably get away of only adding a PackageReference to `ZXing.Net`. The ZXing.Net.Mobile bits provide views that use the camera.

So just remove ZXing.Net.Mobile and add ZXing.Net.